# Inserting into an array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, data-structures

In this task, you need to illustrate the process of inserting an element into an array. The input is the initial array, the item to insert, and the position to insert. As a result, it is necessary to display a log of the element insertion process in a fixed format.

**Input format**
The first line contains the number of elements in the original array. The second line contains the array itself. The third line contains a pair of numbers / textitn, / textitpos - the element to insert and the insertion position

**Output format**
Log of the algorithm in the specified format

Initial array:
15
Element to insert: 11
Position to insert: 0
Operations:
15 15
11 15
Total operations: 2

I don't undrestand what they wants here can anyone help me please?

Comment: surely somebody will help, but they expect some initial effort from asker

Answer (score 0):

They want see how to use memory, how to move data and so on. First, think simply!

Example:

```
3      3        3        3
1 2 3  1 2 3 _  1 _ 2 3  1 4 2 3
2 4    2 4      2 4      2
```

In this case, place 4 onto 2. But memory lacks. So allocate memory. And then open position 2. Finally, 4 move to 2 so accomplished!
All that is left is this moves write down to code.

Comment: In C language ,first value of control variable start from 0 to last value of control -1 ,in your example the result should be 1 2 4 3 not 1 4 2 3

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you

I use two array, the first to fill the array elements and the second for the even elements of the first array, then I read the value of the insert and its index and I shift the elements with a for loop, then I display the Array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    do
    {
         printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
         scanf("%d", &size);
    }while(size<1);
   int num[size+1];
   int num2[size];
   int j=0;
   printf("Enter the elements\n");

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
        printf("Put the %d element :",i);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        if(num[i]%2==0)
        {
             num2[j]=num[i];
             j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe Numbers pairs are :\n");

    for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
          printf("[%d]",num2[k]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

   int val,index_val;
   printf("Give me the value :");
   scanf("%d",&val);

   do
   {
        printf("Give me the index of insertion of this value :");
        scanf("%d",&index_val);
   }while(index_val<0||index_val>size);

    for(int p=size-1;p>=index_val;p--)//element shift loop
    {
          num[p+1]=num[p];
    }
    num[index_val]=val;

    printf("\nDisplay Of the Array :\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
    {
         printf("[%d]",num[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```